# Install wine application launchers in /usr/share/applications instead than /root/.local/share/applications

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, wine, .desktop

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using Xorg.
When I first run a Windows application installer using wine without the sudo command, the application launchers of the installed program go to `~/.local/share/applications` while the wine path goes to `~/.wine`. With sudo I expected them to go to `/usr/share/applications` and instead, to my bitter surprise they go to `/root/.local/share/applications` while the wine path goes to the correct path `/etc/wine`.
How do I change the default path of the wine application launchers to `/usr/share/applications` when I first run a Windows application installer with the sudo command?

Comment: Do you really want [to run Wine as root](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Should_I_run_Wine_as_root.3F)?

Comment: @StephenKitt Of course!

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you want to install applications in this manner. If the goal is to share a prefix among multiple users, that tends not to work very well...

Comment: I have read about the daunting risks, but yeah, basically I want to share a prefix among multiple users. If there was a way to do this without necessarily being root, it would be convenient for the reasons explained in the FAQ.

Comment: Unfortunately, [sharing prefixes can lead to registry corruption](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_install_applications_to_be_shared_by_multiple_users.3F).